# Rebase onto branch that has merge commits

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I am still trying to decide on the Git workflow for our project. It's very confusing and somewhat hard to grasp. I am probably missing something obvious or doing it completely wrong. Here goes one of the scenarios that is happening pretty often

#### Scenario

- create feature branch from master (*always stable*)
- do some commit on feature branch
- master gets new commits that **feature branch wants to use**

#### Goal

Goal is to have nice and tidy history on the master without commits with useless comments like "fixes" or "wip". Those happens for people that are moving along multiple computers or just want to help with something from other team member.

#### Old way

We were doing `git rebase origin/master` at this point in the past. However then it had to be followed by `git pull --rebase` so it can be pushed without `--force` to remote. That was causing some havoc especially when that branch was shared with other people.

#### New way

Now we are trying different approach and doing regular `git merge origin/master` which creates ugly merge commit on feature branch, but it's the fastest and usually painless route. However when feature branch is finished, nightmare begins again. We would like to use **rebase** do squash those feature commits to  roughly 1-3 commits depending on complexity and especially we want to get rid of those merge commits that happened in the middle out of necessity.

Thing is, that there are usually many conflicts that are sometimes rather painful to solve, especially when the changes to file are split in multiple commits. Solving conflict at one point in history usually creates another conflict for the next commit. It's somewhat hard to remember how was that file looking at that particular commit.

So I am doing `git rebase -i --onto <feature-branch> -p origin/master`. I am not sure about that `-p` (*--preserve-merges*). When use it, the commits before latest merge commits are just skipped. It's somewhat hard to me to understand what is happening there and why. Without `-p` it's taking all commits from very beginning of the branch and even more conflicts happens.

#### Ultimate goal

Essentially what I would like to achieve is to take snapshop of the files made from all those commits in feature branch and just make one new commit from that. That would be probably achievable using diff to make patch and then apply that patch on the master. However all history is lost in there and if I would like to see who and when added this change, it would be practically impossible to find.

Comment: Seems like you're making things more complicated than they should be.  Typically it would look like this:  `git checkout master ; git pull ; git checkout feature ; git rebase master ; git checkout master ; git merge feature ; git push`  Obviously you can do a -i on the rebase command if you want to squash commits.  If fixing conflicts is causing more conflicts, it sounds like you don't have a good handle on what's going on with your code.  However, it's difficult for anyone to give specific advice on that issue.

Comment: Oh I wish it would be that easy :( You have missed the part, when I am on feature branch and some critical update has been made to `master` that I need to use in feature branch.

Comment: This is old, and maybe this is obvious, but you also want to do a `git fetch --all` or similar before you rebase. `git pull` does a fetch, but `git rebase` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Essentially what I would like to achieve is to take snapshot of the files made from all those commits in feature branch and just make one new commit from that

You can do this like so:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --squash feature
$ git commit -m'squashed merge of feature'
```

Note, however, that you lose the parent-child relationship between the feature branch and the merge commit. This means that doing more work on the feature branch later, and re-merging, is problematic (since git has no way of correctly finding the common ancestor).

Comment: Awesome, that's pretty much like I have said with that diff. It's definitely viable and easy solution, however that would mean that all work on the `master` would be basically done by me as I am the one making merges. I would have to keep original branches for the reference. I have to think about that. Thank you.

Comment: Keeping history is important in my opinion. There are times when you want to ask developer why he did it that way he did. Having it squashed this way means loosing all that history :(

Comment: You're specifically asking for a way _not_ to keep all the history - or at least to be selective about which history you keep. Those merges you don't want - they're still a genuine part of the development process even if they're not the bit you're interested in seeing. Even if you just rebase them away, you still lose information (like when your feature went from working to broken, due to a rebase)

Comment: You are right of course. Haven't realized that before. Thank you, this will suffice, at least for now.